# When keying dates in the DD/MM/YYYY format, some swap the DD/MM to MM/DD

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a userform to log data into a spreadsheet. During data validation, when I key in dates in the DD/MM/YYYY format, some rows swap the DD/MM to MM/DD.

I adjusted the data type for the entire column, but the userform code seems to act differently for the particular row.

Data from spreadsheet
[image]

Userform Date segment
[image]

Code for transfer information:

```vb
'Transfer information
Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = p
Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = hour.Value & ":" & minute.Value & " " & ampm.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = PTID.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = cmbdate.Value & "/" & cmbmonth.Value & "/" & cmbyear.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = UNIT.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = PCBOX.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 7).Value = WASTE.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 8).Value = REPORTED.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 9).Value = DETBOX.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 10).Value = FOLBOX.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 11).Value = SUMBOX.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 12).Value = CAPBOX.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 13).Value = EHOR.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 14).Value = TECHS.Value & "," & TECHS2.Value & "," & TECHS3.Value & "," & TECHS4.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 15).Value = ERRORBOX.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 16).Value = PREVBOX.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 17).Value = SOP.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 18).Value = AUDIFILE.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 19).Value = INTERFILE.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 20).Value = cmbdate2.Value & "/" & cmbmonth2.Value & "/" & cmbyear2.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 23).Value = Phase.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 24).Value = QIM.Value
MsgBox "Please check your entry in the sheet", , "Entry Complete"
MsgBox "Your entry serial number is " & p

SN.Text = p

VNCFORM.Hide
```

Code for recall information (to same userform, when a serial number for the entry is entered into the userform)

```vb
Private Sub SN_AfterUpdate()

'TO RETRIEVE S/N DATA TO THE USERFORM'

Dim x As Range
Dim y As Long
Set WS = Worksheets("Data")

y = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(CLng(Me.SN.Value), WS.Range("A:A"), 0)
'POSSIBLE PROBLEM AREA'
    Me.cmbdate.Value = Left(WS.Range("B" & y).Value, 2)
    Me.cmbmonth.Value = Mid(WS.Range("B" & y).Value, 4, 2)
    Me.cmbyear.Value = Right(WS.Range("B" & y).Value, 4)
    
    Me.hour.Value = CStr(Left(WS.Range("C" & y).Value, 2))
    Me.minute.Value = CStr(Mid(WS.Range("C" & y).Value, 4, 2))
    Me.ampm.Value = CStr(Right(WS.Range("C" & y).Value, 2))
    
    Me.PTID.Value = WS.Range("D" & y).Value
    Me.UNIT.Value = WS.Range("E" & y).Value
    Me.PCBOX.Value = WS.Range("F" & y).Value
    Me.WASTE.Value = WS.Range("G" & y).Value
    Me.REPORTED.Value = WS.Range("H" & y).Value
    Me.DETBOX.Value = WS.Range("I" & y).Value
    Me.FOLBOX.Value = WS.Range("J" & y).Value
    Me.SUMBOX.Value = WS.Range("K" & y).Value
    Me.CAPBOX.Value = WS.Range("L" & y).Value
    Me.EHOR.Value = WS.Range("M" & y).Value
 
    'Techs involved in case transcribed back to userform
    
    Dim MYARRAY() As String, MYSTRING As String
    MYSTRING = WS.Range("N" & y).Value
    MYARRAY = Split(MYSTRING, ",")
    For N = 0 To UBound(MYARRAY)
        Me.TECHS.Value = MYARRAY(0)
        Me.TECHS2.Value = MYARRAY(1)
        Me.TECHS3.Value = MYARRAY(2)
        Me.TECHS4.Value = MYARRAY(3)
    Next N
    
    Me.ERRORBOX.Value = WS.Range("O" & y).Value
    Me.PREVBOX.Value = WS.Range("P" & y).Value
    Me.SOP.Value = WS.Range("Q" & y).Value
    Me.AUDIFILE.Value = WS.Range("R" & y).Value
    Me.INTERFILE.Value = WS.Range("S" & y).Value
    Me.cmbdate2.Value = Left(WS.Range("T" & y).Value, 2)
    Me.cmbmonth2.Value = Mid(WS.Range("T" & y).Value, 4, 2)
    Me.cmbyear2.Value = Right(WS.Range("T" & y).Value, 4)
    Me.Phase.Value = WS.Range("W" & y).Value
    Me.QIM.Value = WS.Range("X" & y).Value
End Sub
```

The problem seems to occur when I recall data into the userform where the month value and the date values get swapped.
Is there a property of code I am overlooking? Or could I improve the code somehow; I think the error comes from the recall segment (see: 'POSSIBLE PROBLEM AREA')

Comment: Is your local default date format dd/mm/yyy or mm/dd/yyy ?  Are you storing dates on the worksheet in date-formatted cells, or as text?

Comment: @TimWilliams the data keyed into the userform are string values, but the excel column data type is as short date, is this why the numbers are recalled in the opposite direction? The local default date format of the CPU OS is set to DD/MM/YYYY. Should I change the column to General/Text?

Comment: If (eg) `WS.Range("T" & y).Value` is an actual Date value, then you should probably be using `Year()`, `Month()`, `Day()` to extract the date parts, instead of using string functions.

Comment: I don't believe I set the transfer code to convert the data to dates, only to add a "/" between the values keyed into the comboboxes. I don't know what is causing the values to swap when I just use indexing to recall values back into the userform. How would I go about using `Year()`,`Month()`, `Day()` if I should adjust both codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make sure when writing/reading dates you're being more explicit:

```vb
'write date to sheet
Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = DateSerial(CLng(cmbyear.Value), _
                                      CLng(cmbmonth.Value), _
                                      CLng(cmbdate.Value))
                                      
'read date from sheet
Dim dt As Date
dt = WS.Range("B" & y).Value
Me.cmbdate.Value = Day(dt)
Me.cmbmonth.Value = Month(dt)
Me.cmbyear.Value = Year(dt)
```

Also likely need some code to check there's an entry before trying to write/read it.

Comment: Thank you! It's resolved the issue and code works wonderfully.

Comment: The idea of explicitly extracting date is brilliant.